# If all div have no Class do stuff

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I would like to do something with several div's inside ul li: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76NNp/4/)

I'm trying to do **nothing** if one of the ul li div's has a class `.Class` How can I change this code so that nothing happens UNLESS none of the div's have a class?

As you can see now the last li is red, but it shouldn't because the second div has class `.Class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always test for the existence of elements before calling out to style it:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($('ul').find('li div.Class').length == 0)
       $('ul').find('li div').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
$(function () {
    var uls = $('ul li div:not(.Class)');

    if (uls.length > 0) {
        uls.css('color', 'red')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats another way of writing it(looks a bit the same as other answer) Thanks but Im going to accept previous answer

Comment: This is not correct as this would just look for that last `div`. OP wan't to look into all `li's > div` for class `Class`

Comment: @Youss yeah it's basically the same outcome, I just prefer to cram all the sectors in one statement :)

Comment: @mattytommo Everyone has his own taste I think(, but I dont think it really matter in such sort pieces of code)